# OGR error creating geometry for feature when deleting nodes

Tags: qgis, ogr, nodes

I have a line Shapefile that I need to remove many nodes from.

Some I can delete fine, others delete but when I hit save I receive the following error:
OGR error creating geometry for feature

Using QGIS version 2.14.0-Essen in Win10 64 bit.

Any ideas? I've converted it to multipoint then back to single point with no change.

Comment: It would be nice if you can capture one such feature and copy it alone into a new layer which you could save and put available for downloading. Or simply add the geometry into your question as WKT.

Comment: I managed to get around the issue with a feature query hiding the nodes I wanted to delete. This is the layer I am working on.https://data.linz.govt.nz/layer/221-nz-railway-centrelines-topo-1500k/    I am trying to delete all railways other than the 'North Island Main Trunk'. It's annoying me as now I have a layer with far more data in it than I need.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting the feature and then deleting it after selection:

1. Turn on Toggle Editing
2. Select Features by Area or Single Click > Select Features (you can choose to select by click, polygon, freehand, or radius). 3) Once the desired feature is selected, you can delete it.

If you are trying to delete an entire feature by deleting nodes or "deleting part of feature", this usually generates an error (from my experience).